# nginx auth to mysql backend

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, nginx, proxy

I am using an Nginx reverse proxy to tie back to a MySQL DB store. I need to write an authentication service for a reverse IMAP/SMTP proxy.

There are two examples on the Nginx wiki to tie back to most databases: an embedded Perl and a PHP script. I am not familiar with Perl and since my HTTP server uses PHP to tie back to MySQL using PDO statements, I am more comfortable with the PHP script, seen here:

[Using a PHP Script on an Apache Server as the IMAP Auth Backend](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/imapauthenticatewithapachephpscript/)

My problem is that I don't know exactly what I need to input inside the functions since it just mentions to put your logic here. If you scroll a bit down, you will see two functions: `authuser` and `getmailserver`. Should these be PDO prepare statements to select the email with `LIMIT 1`?

Would appreciate any help with this.

Comment: Why do you think that you need whatever "nginx auth to mysql backend"?  What is that backend then?

Comment: Sorry. I need to write an authentication service for a reverse imap proxy. I can see I did not mention that, apologies.

Answer (score 1):

> Should these be PDO prepare statements

Generally speaking - yes

> to select the email with LIMIT 1?

I doubt so. You don't need no email here. for the authuser you need only boolean

```
function authuser($user,$pass){
    global $pdo;
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT pass FROM users WHERE login = ?");
    $stmt->execute([$user]);
    $dbpass = $stmt->fetchColumn();
    return password_verify($pass, $dbpass); // should be hashed this way 
}
```

getmailserver have to return server. if you have only one then

```
function getmailserver($user) {
    return 'server';
}
```

Comment: Ok I'm going to test this soon but just a quick question on the SELECT statement. You are assuming that my password column in my users table is called "pass" correct? Also is "login" assumed to be the user's username, meaning the email? Because that is what I meant my email. We use "email" as the column for the username since we only store users as their full emails. And finally, when you mentioned hashing for the password, assuming we just use md5, how would I rewrite the return line for that? I will be testing this shortly. Thanks!

Comment: Well if you need confirmation for *such* details - then better hire a programmer

Comment: I must agree with you